# Python list index out of range error

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("email_addresses_of_ALL_purchasers.csv")
all_emails = df["Email"]
real_emails = [] 

test_domains = ['yahoo.com', 'gmail.com', 'facebook.com', 'hotmail.com']

for email in all_emails: 
    email_separated = email.split("@")
    if email_separated[1] not in test_domains:
        real_emails.append(email) 
print real_emails
```

I'm trying to filter out different email account types. Why does this above code produce an error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: "List index out of range" is a pretty self-explanatory error message IMO. Take a look at the actual data that's causing the error.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently one of your emails does not contain a @.

Put a `print(email)` as first statement of the loop, then you can see which email doesn't fit.

Comment: +1 Before anything else, when debugging you should `print` the variables so that what you expect to be in them is actually in them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("email_addresses_of_ALL_purchasers.csv")
all_emails = df["Email"]
real_emails = [] 

test_domains = ['yahoo.com', 'gmail.com', 'facebook.com', 'hotmail.com']

for email in all_emails: 
    email_separated = email.split("@")
    try:
        if email_separated[1] not in test_domains:
            real_emails.append(email)
    except IndexError:
        print('Mail {} does not contain a @ sign'.format(email))
print real_emails
```

Comment: We could use `pandas` directly too: `print all_emails[~all_emails.str.contains("@")]`

Answer (score 0):

More robust to use `partition` here. If the `@` is missing - `domain` will simply be the empty string

```
for email in all_emails: 
    name, delim, domain = email.partition("@")
    if domain and domain not in test_domains:
```

Also wikipedia has a [list of unusual but valid email address examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses) that may surprise you